# Improved import export extension magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, importexport

I want to try this extension https://firebearstudio.com/blog/improved-import-export-2-0.html so i found this link on github : https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree but when i installed it i just found this interface : 
[image]

but i am supposed to have this interface instead 
[image]
i think that this code miss some folders so have anyone tried this extension free  or buy it how do you find it for resolving problem of import. I really need your help

Answer (score 0):

The youtube screenshot is a full version of an import-export extension.

Comment: so it's paid not free

Comment: Yes, bcoz I already used a paid version in one of my projects.

Comment: so can i ask you a question about this extension please

Comment: what about the import functionnality and specially configurable product do you tried this

Comment: it's working perfectly fine but you have to modify the csv format.

Comment: ok thanks  a lot

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155215)

Comment: Yes you are right, but how can I give demo hear @Mohit Kumar Arora

Comment: please give me a demo @Biren Patel